# Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@releaseUnitTest/compileClasspath'

Tags: java, android

Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@releaseUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0. Open File Show Details

Could not resolve com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0.
Required by:

> Could not resolve com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0.
>   Could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/26.1.0/appcompat-v7-26.1.0.pom'.
>   Could not GET 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/26.1.0/appcompat-v7-26.1.0.pom'.
>   dl.google.com

Answer (score 0):

Do you have this on your gradle repositories ?

If you're using a version of Gradle lower than 4.1

```
maven {
    url 'https://maven.google.com'
}
```

else :

```
google()
```

Comment: Hi I tried this but i am still getting the same error. I am using gradle version 4.1

Comment: Can you add your gradle files ? Thanks